# How to use Body Listener in FosRestBundle in Symfony

Tags: php, fosrestbundle

How to use the Body Listener in FosRestBundle In Symfony.I dont have the clear idea about it.Please anyone can help me

Thanks,
in advance

Answer (score 0):

*Symfony 6 

FOSRestBundle 3*

**1. Add to file:**
`config/packages/fos_rest.yaml`

```
fos_rest:

    body_listener:
        enabled: true
```

**2. Create a controller method:**
`App\Controller\PostController`

```
class PostController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    #[Route(
        path: '/api/post',
        methods: 'POST'
    )]
    public function createAction(
        Request $request
    ) {
        dd($request->request);
    }
}
```

**3. Send a POST request to the specified path:**

Headers: `Content-type: application/json` *(very important!)*
Body:    `{"Foo":"Bar"}`

**4. We see the result:**
The raw JSON will be deserialized and packaged in the $request property.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read the related documentation before ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html

It should help you on using Body Listener.

Comment: to be fair, the documentation is very lacking, Im trying something very simple (for it to decode a JSON request body) and styill after reading that I have no idea how to configure ir or how to retrieve the values